# really return id column when we make insert row?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table test
id - int, primary key, auto_incriment
name - varchar(100)

INSERT INTO test
  (ID, Name)
VALUES
  ('$ID', '$Name');
```

Tell me please really return `ID` in one query when we make insert ?

Comment: I guess this is you are looking for [*`LAST_INSERT_ID()`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: You cannot return it in one query, unless you build a stored procedure that performs the insert then queries for the last inserted id.  But MySQL provides `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for the purpose: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and most language-specific APIs have a wrapper method for it.

Comment: Or switch to sql server and use OUTPUT clause.

Comment: @Mihai Or switch to Postgres and use the `returning` clause - which actually produces a result set

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, i would like find info for mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*as say @MichaelBerkowski you cannt return `ID` in one query.*

*For return `ID` make next:*

```
INSERT INTO test
  (ID, Name)
VALUES
  ('$ID', '$Name');

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

*inforamtion about `LAST_INSERT_ID();` you are can read **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)***

Answer (score 0):

Since ID is auto incrementing, don't specify it in your query, you can simply do

```
INSERT INTO test
(Name)
VALUES
('$Name');
```

(Note if this is coming from PHP, be sure to watch out for SQL injection problems!)

If you specify an ID it will override MySQL's normal operations (which can be useful on occasion but not likely in this case).

You can refer back to the last inserted ID using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. (note the column has to be inserted first, you can't call this and then insert with that value)